# Find difference between many datetime columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Dataframe with 282 columns, and 14000 rows. It looks as follows:

```
                                    0           1               ...     282
uref_fixed      
0006d730f5aa8492a59150e35bca5cc6    3/26/2018   7/3/2018        ...
00076311c47c44c33ffb834b1cebf5db    5/13/2018   5/13/2018       ...
0009ba8a69924902a9692c5f3aacea7f    7/13/2018   None            ...
000dccb863b913226bca8ca636c9ddce    11/5/2017   11/10/2017      ...
```

I am trying to end up with a column at index 0 which, for each row, shows the average of the difference between each consecutive date value in each row (ie. difference date in column 2 and 3, then difference 3 and 4, then difference 4 and 5 etc., and then the average of all these)

Please note, there can be up to 282 date values in a row, but as you can see many have less.

Cheers

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a **[mcve]**. That means no images / links.

Comment: What do you want to do in the case of `None` values? for instance, what is the average between `7/13/2018` and `None`?

Comment: Once there is 'none' it continues as such, hence there are no more time difference values to obtain in that row so it would finish for that row

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
#df is your dataframe, df2 is a new one you have to initialize as empty
def diffdate(df, col1, col2):
    if df[col1]==None or df[col2]==None:
        return None
    date1 = [int(i) for i in df[col1].split('/')]
    date2 = [int(i) for i in df[col2].split('/')]
    return (dt(date2[2],date2[0],date2[1]) - dt(date1[2],date1[0],date1[1])).days
for i in range(len(df.columns)-1):
    df2[i] = df.apply(lambda x: diffdate(df, i, i+1),axis = 1)
```

df2 will hold all of the consecutive pair differences. Averaging the rows after this is pretty simple.

Comment: Hi thanks for your help. This solution is returning ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: And make sure to hit that green check on the left!

Comment: hi thanks for your help again but still getting the same error

Comment: every test case I run is perfectly fine